# Trying to send POST data with AJAX to PHP script but it crashes on linebreaks and '

Tags: php, ajax

I've been banging my head on this for the past 12 hours and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Basically, I'm sending POST data from a form to a PHP file using AJAX:

`"&textareacomments=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("textareacomments").value);
xmlhttp.open("POST", "php/order.php?action=save", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xmlhttp.send(contenu);`

But when my PHP file receive it, it reads just fine all data and text regular "input" like this:

`$telephone = urldecode(htmlentities($_POST['telephone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));`

BUT then I try to read the TEXTAREA POST and if I insert a `linebreak` or `'` then something crashes and the script doesn't run.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for your help

Joel

Answer (score 0):

textareacomments is a GET variable and will be on $_GET and not $_POST.

Comment: Ok thanks, I changed to this: `$textareacomments = htmlentities($_GET['textareacomments'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` but it still doesn't work.. And furthermore, when I just type let's say `aaaa` with no linebreaks or `'` it works (with POST).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to url encode your upload before sending it to php.  Use Javascript to do something like this:

```
function urlencode(myText) {
    myText = encodeURIComponent(myText);
    return myText.replace(/~/g,'%7E').replace(/%20/g,'+');
}
```